# git: clone ony a subdirectory

Tags: git, directory, repository, clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Dear All,
is there a method to clone only a directory from an entire repository?

thank you,
cheers

daniele